# choose the proper clustering method for Latent Semantic Analysis

Tags: cluster-analysis, latent-semantic-indexing, latent-semantic-analysis

i want to cluster some text document to find the document with the same concept. i've done the semantic similarity using Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA), but i confuse which clustering method that i should choose for my purpose .
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use hierarchical clustering. There is a package in R called RClusterpp which is very efficient for hierarchical clustering of large data (it does a parallel computation). Then you can cut the dendrogram tree for different number of cluster within the possible range and check for cluster profiles using cross-tab.